# How to determine an iPhone's rear camera field of view programmatically

Tags: swift, iphone

I'm trying to ensure I can photograph the full width of something reliably at a set distance.

How can I programmatically determine an iPhone's rear wide angle lens horizontal angle/field of view in landscape orientation?

Answer (score 3):

In Swift, given an instance of `AVCaptureDevice`, `backCameraDevice`:

```
print(backCameraDevice.activeFormat.videoFieldOfView)
```

Which according to the documentation, "Indicates the format’s horizontal field of view in degrees."